# Angular2: oauth2 with token headers

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm new to angular2. In 1.* everything was fine with interceptors, just add them: and you have everywhere your headers, and you can handle your requests, when token became invalid...

In `angular2` i'm using `RxJs`.
So i get my token:

```
  getToken(login: string, pwd: string): Observable<boolean> {

    let bodyParams = {
      grant_type: 'password',
      client_id: 'admin',
      scope: AppConst.CLIENT_SCOPE,
      username: login,
      password: pwd
    };

    let params = new URLSearchParams();
    for (let key in bodyParams) {
      params.set(key, bodyParams[key])
    }

    let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'});
    let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});

    return this.http.post(AppConst.IDENTITY_BASE_URI + '/connect/token', params.toString(), options)
      .map((response: Response) => {
        let data = response.json();

        if (data) {
          this.data = data;
          localStorage.setItem('auth', JSON.stringify({
            access_token: data.access_token,
            refresh_token: data.refresh_token
          }));
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      });
  }
```

and then how can i use this token in every request? i don't want to set `.header` in every request. It's a bad practice.

And then: for example when i do any request, and get `401`-error, how can i intercept, and get a new token, and then resume all requests, like it was in `angular 1`?

i tried to use `JWT` from here [jwt](https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt), but it doesn't meet my requirements, btw in first angular i was using `Restangular` - and everything was fine there (also with manual on tokens:https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#seterrorinterceptor)

Comment: You can either extend the default http service and use the extended version, or you could create a method that gets some parameters (if necessary) and return a RequestOptions objects to pass default http service.

Comment: @s.alem example plz

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either extend the default http service and use the extended version, or you could create a method that gets some parameters (if necessary) and return a RequestOptions objects to pass default http service.

**Option 1**

You can create a service:

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpUtils {
  constructor(private _cookieService: CookieService) { }

  public optionsWithAuth(method: RequestMethod, searchParams?: URLSearchParams): RequestOptionsArgs {
    let headers = new Headers();
    let token = 'fancyToken';
    if (token) {
      headers.append('Auth', token);
    }
    return this.options(method, searchParams, headers);
  }

  public options(method: RequestMethod, searchParams?: URLSearchParams, header?: Headers): RequestOptionsArgs {
    let headers = header || new Headers();
    if (!headers.has('Content-Type')) {
      headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    }
    let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
    if (method === RequestMethod.Get || method === RequestMethod.Delete) {
      options.body = '';
    }
    if (searchParams) {
      options.params = searchParams;
    }
    return options;
  }

  public handleError(error: Response) {
    return (res: Response) => {
      if (res.status === 401) {
        // do something
      }
      return Observable.throw(res);
    };
  }
}
```

Usage example:

```
this._http
  .get('/api/customers', this._httpUtils.optionsWithAuth(RequestMethod.Get))
  .map(res => <Customer[]>res.json())
  .catch(err => this._httpUtils.handleError(err));
```

This example is using cookies to store and access the token. You could use a parameter as well.

---

**Option 2**

Second option is to extend http service, for example like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, XHRBackend, RequestOptions, Request, RequestOptionsArgs, Response, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

@Injectable()
export class MyHttp extends Http {

  constructor (backend: XHRBackend, options: RequestOptions) {
    let token = 'fancyToken';
    options.headers.set('Auth', token);
    super(backend, options);
  }

  request(url: string|Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    let token = 'fancyToken';
    if (typeof url === 'string') {
      if (!options) {
        options = {headers: new Headers()};
      }
      options.headers.append('Auth', token);
    } else {
      url.headers.append('Auth', token);
    }
    return super.request(url, options).catch(this.handleError(this));
  }

  private handleError (self: MyHttp) {
    return (res: Response) => {
      if (res.status === 401) {
        // do something
      }
      return Observable.throw(res);
    };
  }
}
```

And in your `@NgModule`:

```
@NgModule({
  // other stuff ...
  providers: [
    {
      provide: MyHttp,
      useFactory: (backend: XHRBackend, options: RequestOptions) => {
        return new MyHttp(backend, options);
      },
      deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions]
    }
  ]
  // a little bit more other stuff ...
})
```

Usage:

```
@Injectable()
class CustomerService {

  constructor(private _http: MyHttp) {
  }

  query(): Observable<Customer[]> {
    return this._http
      .get('/api/customers')
      .map(res => <Customer[]>res.json())
      .catch(err => console.log('error', err));
  }
}
```

**Extra:**

If you want to use refresh token to obtain a new token you can do something like this:

```
private handleError (self: MyHttp, url?: string|Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs) {
  return (res: Response) => {
    if (res.status === 401 || res.status === 403) {
      let refreshToken:string = 'fancyRefreshToken';
      let body:any = JSON.stringify({refreshToken: refreshToken});
      return super.post('/api/token/refresh', body)
        .map(res => {
          // set new token
        }) 
        .catch(err => Observable.throw(err))
        .subscribe(res => this.request(url, options), err => Observable.throw(err));
    }
    return Observable.throw(res);
  };
}
```

To be honest, I haven't tested this, but it could provide you at least a starting point.

Comment: how can i repeat all my requests, if i got 401? in stack-way?

Comment: `return Observable.throw(error || 'Server error');` but you do not repeat your request :)

Comment: Check the both options, pick whichever suits you better.

Comment: second is cool, but... you only catch you request-error, how to repeat it?

Comment: What do you mean by repeating it?

Comment: For example: i have two tokens (auth_token & refresh_token). Auth token is valid only for 5min, then i need to refresh it with my refresh token (so, how is working oauth2). I have my form-page opened for 6min, i send my data to server, and get 401 error - then i have to get new auth-token, and invisible for user repeat all my requests - this was pretty easy with angular 1.* and interceptors. I don't wanna handle every unsuccessful server-call in every method. Is it clear now, or not?

Comment: I see now. You can put refreshing mechanism into the handleError method. It shouldn't be too difficult to adapt the method in the answer to your needs.

Comment: ok, thx

also: https://pastebin.com/raw/U4MnYZJV this code throws a lot of errors: https://pastebin.com/raw/TPH4Cjmh

everything was fine on your machine?

Comment: It is fine on my machine. I have added the imports, could you change your imports as the answer.

Comment: Basically, if the error status is 401 or 403, you can make a call from the error handling method to the refreshing endpoint and record the token wherever it is necessary. But be sure that you are using `super.request()`, otherwise you can trigger an infinite recursive method calling.

Comment: stupid me... how can i get current request in handleError, and resend it?

Comment: We all go blind sometimes, no worries. I made a little edit, I hope it will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

We solved the issue with extension of AuthHttp. We added a method a on AuthHttp to set a new header dynamically like that (X-RoleId is a custom header)

```
declare module 'angular2-jwt' {
  interface AuthHttp {
    setRoleId(config: {});
  }
}

AuthHttp.prototype.setRoleId = function (roleId) {
  let jsThis = <any>(this);
  jsThis.config.globalHeaders = [
          {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, 
          {'X-RoleId': roleId}
          ];
};
```

Comment: 'angular2-jwt' is working only with tokens, like xxx.yyy.zzz

Comment: token for sure + we set a custom header based on received token

Comment: unfortunately, i have another token schema, not xxx.yyy.zzz